Telegram A version doesn't allow starting mini app using direct link
Telegram mini app allow users to start app with direct link like:
https://t.me/appbotname_bot?startapp
Direct link works in telegram platform correctly.
For e.g, if I click telegram mini app link posted in some channel then it starts mini app correctly both in A version and K version(in Web).
But if I paste this url in browser address bar, it doesn't open mini app in and only in A version.
When I paste it on address bar in K version, it does open telegram and then starts mini app, but in A version it doesn't open mini app.
If I eliminate ?startapp from url, then it opens bot in A version.
So is there any way to allow ...?startapp open telegram mini app in A version?
